# Name for a special point on a curve

Tags: calculus, functions, terminology, graphing-functions

I have a curve, represented by a function $y = f(x)$, and a very special point $S$ on that curve. It is "special" in the following ways:

- the first derivative of $f(x)$ in the neighborhood of $S$ is positive
- the second derivative of $f(x)$ in the neighborhood of $S$ is negative, and has reached its maximum value
- the third derivative of $f(x)$ in the neighborhood of $S$ is zero
- the fourth derivative of $f(x)$ in the neighborhood of $S$ is negative

I've illustrated the function and its third derivative in the graph below. **My question is**, does this special point S on the blue curve have some meaningful name?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. The answer to your question is "no". If it's special for you in some application you can give it a name. (I think the red label on your graph should say "fourth derivative".)

Comment: Thanks, Ethan. The labeling is as intended. The red line represents the third derivative. Point S on a curve is where the third derivative becomes zero.

Comment: Just to answer my own question, I would call point S the "elbow". But I am still wondering if there is an official name (and meaning) for it.